# Azure Data factory vs Data sync

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-sync

Our assignment is to copy & transform data from on-premises SQL Server into Azure SQL database once in a day. We have made some tech trials and both Azure Data Factory and Data Sync are technically possible approaches for our problem.

So, what are the key decision drivers in selecting between Data Factory & Data Sync? One driver is naturally the cost. Any educated guesses on Azure Data Sync cost when it will be generally available?

Comment: how you achieved to perform ETL load using data sync?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory is to primarily ingest data to Azure. It can be streaming data, rdbms data, iot data etc., Whereas Synch framework is primarily for synch between your on-prem to SQL Azure. So if you have a requirement only to synch go for synch framework not with ADF

Comment: It is my understanding that Data Sync is still under preview. And from what I've experienced it is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an ETL workload to perform not just replicating data. So you need a data factory to achieve.

Azure Data Sync is the best solution for hybrid data sync.